# installing packages with pip returns error

Tags: python, cmd, pip, package

a while ago i downloaded pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
before i realised my version of python allready comes with pip. i succesfully used it to download pygame but now i am trying to download numpy and no matter what i try it returns the error below.

i have tried reinstalling pip and python but nothing changed. i think it has something to do with me accidently downloading pip from the link above and having two versions of pip. and it isn't the one being uninstalled when i uninstall pip, if any of that makes sense. anyway that's just my theory.

this is what happens when i try to install anything

```
C:\Users\riley>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

it might be to do with the link also, as it goes to an errored page. please help i can't do anything with out the package i'm trying to install. solution would be deeply appreciated.

*EDIT*
this post isn't a duplicate of the other question that has been suggested this is a duplicate of as i don't believe the circumstance or the answer of that question is in relation to mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+There+was+a+problem+confirming+the+ssl+certificate+HTTPSConnectionPool

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

`C:\Users\riley> pip install --trusted-host pypi.org numpy`

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/5386668).

Comment: Better: `--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/1608670